# Windows: Running vagrant as administrator not working - works normally

Tags: laravel, npm, vagrant, administrator, npm-install

I've been using vagrant to run laravel/lumen as well as just other general stuff such as node js scripts.  I've run into problems installing some things using npm, and it seems that a solution working for a lot of people is just running the command line (or git bash in my case) as an administrator.  However when I try this and use vagrant up, I get a long list of errors.  I've also tried vagrant init which gives the same errors.

Here are the errors

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
v==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => C:/Users/Andy McNally/Homestead
vag    default: /home/vagrant/home => C:/Users/Andy McNally/home
r==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use
the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always
will still run.
```

Comment: do you try `vagrant provision`?

Comment: Just did, same errors :/

Comment: having same issue